# Selenium webdriver find texy by first digits

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with looking for element with specific, not known id. I know only that it'll start from actual date, so for example it'd be today `'201511276745476574865746375d'`. (it'll be always a letter in the end)

In SQL I'd find it by writting "20151127%" but it doesn't work in Selenium webdriver :(

EDIT:
I use java, I need to click button, which has code:

`<input name="removeCatalog" id="20151130081807817d" class="buttons buttonShort alignCenter" value="Delete" onclick="removeCatalogFromCatalogList('20151130081807817','Do you want to remove it?')" type="submit">`

I tried to use SQL code to find an id, but I realised that webdriver won't always have connection to database (I can't do it that way).

I tried to find a row with "Catalog selenium" keyword, but not working:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='GridView']/tbody/tr[td[text() ='catalog selenium']]/td[8]/input")).click();`

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using? (Needed to provide you with a more robust solution that will also work tomorrow or any other day)

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: I have finally an Internet connection. Well, I don't think it's worth to show - it's a part of a bigger project and my question was as strictly as it'd be (it's a table with documents made by users and I want to delete a specific known one). I tried to connect with SQL database to find a log, but I realised that I don't always have a posibbility to connect with database, so I tried to find different way. My last try was:

Comment: Oops, can't edit - was with SQL line, so it was totally different. I was searching this site to find a hint, but I coundn't have find it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what programming language you're working with, I'll go ahead with C#.
If you know for sure that your ID starts with the current day, then to have a general solution you could have:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, '" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "')]"));
```

Comment: I'm using java, but it's almost the same :) I'll try to check it out, thanks for suggestion

Comment: What if the letter "d" on the end is very important? I changed it to

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, " + year.format(new Date())+ month.format(new Date())+ day.format(new Date()) + ")]"));`

and it works. I tried with:


`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, " + year.format(new Date())+ month.format(new Date())+ day.format(new Date()) + "d)]"));`

Or simmiars way (including "Contains && "d"") and not working :/

Comment: You could have your xPath like this:
`driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, '" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "') and contains(@id, 'd')]"));`

Comment: btw just wondering, there are formats `yyyyMMdd`, but what if I have `yyyyMMddHHMMrrrrrrrd` where r is random digit and d is obligatory? Would it be possible to make selenium to find it?

Comment: Yes, the last part `and contains(@id, 'd')` makes this possible. This forces the webdriver to find an element whose `id` contains the letter `d`. 
And since your `id` only contains numbers (in the form of date and/or time and random digits) and only one letter, then you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I see my mistake in my thoughts - I tried to write `&&` instead of `and` - now it makes perfect sense! :)

Answer (score 2):

To find an element with an *id* attribute starting with *20151127*, you can use the following XPath:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, '20151127')]
```

I would recommend using the actual tag name (div, td etc.) in place of the asterisk given in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '20151127')]")
```